# CSS3 transform rotateY(180deg) - IE fallback

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there an IE fallback for transform rotateY(180deg)? Need a 3D flip animation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have IE8 to test with but I think this might work: (ie5.5+)
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28VS.85%29.aspx

Matrix Filter for IE could be another option: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx

I got the answer from this site when I was playing with something else: 
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Personally when using IE6-8 the tag that works best for me is display: none ;P

Comment: This rotates in the 2d plane. E.g. it corresponds to `transform: rotate(270deg)` - Not `transform: rotateY(270deg)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem last week.  What you need is:

```
.flipHorizontal {
filter: "fliph";
}
```

More specifically, if you want to rotate it continuously on the y axis I've created a jquery plugin to use:

```
**
 * jQuery Rotate On Axis In IE Plugin 1.0.0
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Aryeh Citron
 *
 * Licensed under MIT: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */


(function ($)
{
    $.fn.rotateOnAxisInIE = function (options)
    {
        var settings = $.extend(
        {
            spinSpeed: "slow",
        }, options);

        return this.each(function ()
        {
            var startingInterval;
            switch (settings.spinSpeed)
            {
                case "slow": startingInterval = 0.006; break;
                case "medium": startingInterval = 0.01; break;
                case "fast": startingInterval = 0.03; break;
                default: startingInterval = 0.01; break;
            }

            var image = this;
            var imageWidth = 1;
            var gettingSmaller = true;
            var fullRotation = true;
            var interval = startingInterval;
            var increment = startingInterval / 4;
            var refreshRateInMilliseconds = 35;

            setInterval(function ()
            {
                $(image).css("msTransform", "scaleX(" + imageWidth + ")");
                if (gettingSmaller)
                {
                    interval = interval + increment;
                    imageWidth = imageWidth - interval;
                }
                else
                {
                    interval = interval - increment;
                    imageWidth = imageWidth + interval;
                }

                if (imageWidth <= 0)
                {
                    gettingSmaller = false;
                    if ($(image).css("filter") == "")
                        $(image).css("filter", "fliph");
                    else
                        $(image).css("filter", "");

                    imageWidth = 0.01;
                }
                if (imageWidth >= 1)
                {
                    gettingSmaller = true;
                }

                if (gettingSmaller && interval < 0)
                    interval = 0;

            }, refreshRateInMilliseconds);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Example Usage

```
$("#myImageId").rotateOnAxisInIE();
```

or

```
$("#myImageId").rotateOnAxisInIE({ spinSpeed: "fast" });
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a filter

```
#rotate {
 -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg); //IE9
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that a 2D rotation on the X axis? RotateY flips backwards?

Comment: Tried this but doesn't seem to be working in IE9? Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/lsatdown/j3RFk/