# Flip text vertically retaining case of the text

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any way to flip the text vertically retaining their case sensativness using javascript/php specifically not by css because I want to support old browsers too.

Comment: If you want a javascript solution, why tag as PHP?

Comment: sorry mark i have forgotten to write php in my question but now i have edited it

Comment: what do you mean my flip vertically? Something like transform: rotateX(180deg), but in JS instead of CSS?

Comment: yes something like that **transform:rotate(180deg)** but i want to achieve the approach by javascript or php because css3 is not supported in older devices and browsers.

Comment: I have googled a [link](http://com-dic.blogspot.in/p/flip-text-membuat-text-terbalik.html) but in this case all characters are flipped to lower case only... I want to conserve the case of all letters.

Comment: so you want the text to be upside down?

Comment: javascript can't "flip". it can only alter css rules. PHP has nothing to do with presentation either, unless you want to render the text into an image using GD and flip that. And since you're wanting old browsers, obviously `<canvas>` won't work either.

Comment: there is CSS to support new & old browsers: [How to draw vertical text with CSS cross-browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to rely on JS or PHP to support old browsers (unless you mean *really* old browsers like IE4 or something, and then the JS support would be bad enough that that probably wouldn't help you either).

Internet Explorer 5.5+ has a filter called `Rotation` that should do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb554293(v=vs.85).aspx

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513921/css3-transform-rotatey180deg-ie-fallback)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you *can* rely on JS or PHP for something like this. Unless you can find another character that looks like an upside-down version of every letter, upper and lower case, and then do a replace or something, I guess...